# prototype chain in javaScript returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Can someone help with this problem. Everytime I call **kid.say**, the console returns undefined. I was expecting it to look up the prototype chain giving kid access to the function **say**.

```js
function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
}

// the parent constructor
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'Adam';
}

// adding functionality to the prototype
Parent.prototype.say = function() {
  return this.name;
};

function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
}

// the parent constructor
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'Adam';
}

// adding functionality to the prototype
Parent.prototype.say = function() {
  return this.name;
};

var dad = new Parent();

// child constructor
function Child(name) {
  Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}

var kid = new Child("Patrick");

inherit(kid, dad);

console.log(kid.say);
```

Comment: I've updated your code block to make it a Stack Snippet so it's runnable. To do so, I had to fix a syntax error (you had `function` in front of `inherit(kid, dad)`). So it's probably worth checking the code you're running to see if it has the same problem.

Comment: `kid` has no property `say` so `kid.say` will be undefined.

Comment: `say` is a method so it needs to be called `kid.say()`

Answer (score 3):

That `inherit` function is designed to set up inheritance between two *constructor functions*, not individual objects, but `kid` and `dad` are individual objects.

While it's *possible* (as of ES2015) to change the prototype of an existing object after creating it in a standard way, it's not advisable to do so.

So the issue is really just that you're misusing that `inherit` function. You would want:

```
inherit(Child, Parent);
```

...and you'd want to do it before creating `kid`.

(Also, unrelated, you've assigned to `Parent.prototype.say` **twice**, with the same function definition. Just once is sufficient, I've removed the redundant one below.)

If you do that, it correctly logs the function (because you haven't *called* it, you've only referred to it):

```js
function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
}

// the parent constructor
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'Adam';
}

// adding functionality to the prototype
Parent.prototype.say = function() {
  return this.name;
};

function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
}

// the parent constructor
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'Adam';
}

inherit(Child, Parent);

var dad = new Parent;

// child constructor
function Child(name) {
  Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}

var kid = new Child("Patrick");

console.log(kid.say);
```

If yo meant to *call* it, you'd need `()` after it: `console.log(kid.say());`

```js
function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
}

// the parent constructor
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'Adam';
}

// adding functionality to the prototype
Parent.prototype.say = function() {
  return this.name;
};

function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
}

// the parent constructor
function Parent(name) {
  this.name = name || 'Adam';
}

inherit(Child, Parent);

var dad = new Parent;

// child constructor
function Child(name) {
  Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}

var kid = new Child("Patrick");

console.log(kid.say());
```

---

As of ES2015, there's no longer any need for that `inherit` function, just use the `class` feature (transpiling if you need to support older environments):

```
class Parent {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    say() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}

let kid = new Child("Patrick");

console.log(kid.say()); // Patrick
```

Even in ES5 (December 2009), *that* version of `inherit` was obsoleted by `Object.create`:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

Note that that version of `inherit` leaves out an important step, which is to fix the `constructor` reference on the newly-created prototype object.

```
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```